# print_matrix of munkres library python throws an exception on matrix containing zeroes

Tags: python, hungarian-algorithm

```
Lowest cost through this matrix:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "muncre.py", line 8, in <module>
        print_matrix(matrix, msg='Lowest cost through this matrix:')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/munkres.py", line 730, in    print_matrix
        width = max(width, int(math.log10(val)) + 1)
ValueError: math domain error
```

When the matrix is containing zero in any of the rows, the above error is thrown. How can I fix it?

This is the piece of code in python:

```
from munkres import Munkres, print_matrix
matrix = [[6, 9, 1],
          [10, 9, 2],
          [0,8,7]]
m = Munkres()
indexes = m.compute(matrix)
print_matrix(matrix, msg='Lowest cost through this matrix:')
total = 0
for row, column in indexes:
    value = matrix[row][column]
    total += value
    print '(%d, %d) -> %d' % (row, column, value)
print 'total cost: %d' % total
```

I installed the library munkres using the following command in Ubuntu:

**sudo apt-get install python-munkres**

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i gave a matrix of values  [[6 91][10 9 2][0 8 7]]. In case of any matrix like this form which is containing 0's in any of the rows, muncres is throwing Value error. I couldn't get the role of width in the code of the library.  So how to resolve this ?

Comment: Right, but did you read the page I linked? "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem"

Comment: @tom I edited the question, please check.

Comment: Do you understand the logarithm function, and on which numbers it's defined? Hint: `math.log10(0)` is either not defined, or is equal to negative infinity, depending on your particular needs. Python obviously prefers to consider it an error (i.e. it's not defined), not having an immediately useful concept of negative infinity that plays well with other numbers...

Comment: what is the role of width in the munkres library? Why cant it be 0 ? Do you have any idea regarding any other source which can handle zeroes in the given matrix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really looks like a bug with the munkres library.  The print_matrix is just a "convenience" function and I'd suggest filing a bug report and in the interim just replacing it with something like the following (which is just their code with a fix to avoid trying to apply 0 or negative numbers to the logarithm).  What there were trying to do is make it properly space each column to be the largest width for a number.  Note that if you pass in negative numbers, this may have an off by 1 issue, but on the other hand, if you have negative costs, you may have bigger issues.

```
def print_matrix(matrix, msg=None):
    """
    Convenience function: Displays the contents of a matrix of integers.
    :Parameters:
        matrix : list of lists
            Matrix to print
        msg : str
            Optional message to print before displaying the matrix
    """
    import math

    if msg is not None:
        print(msg)

    # Calculate the appropriate format width.
    width = 1
    for row in matrix:
        for val in row:
            if abs(val) > 1:
               width = max(width, int(math.log10(abs(val))) + 1)

    # Make the format string
    format = '%%%dd' % width

    # Print the matrix
    for row in matrix:
        sep = '['
        for val in row:
            sys.stdout.write(sep + format % val)
            sep = ', '
        sys.stdout.write(']\n')
```